# Compare text representation of binary file

Tags: java, string, text, comparison, diff

I have two xml reports from the execution of two programs. Such reports contain a section which lists all the i/o operation executed, along with the content of each one. Some of them are xml, others are binary, but data contained within the report is always textual, so I have something similar to this:

```
.....0.................. .......................@........'F...O)v...O*......................0..........l...c...=
Y!...!pvw.........(.........E...
yY...-qVC......p...K,......Pm.........Si4........,.......C0....?0....'...................K0....0
.   *...H......
....0I1.0   ..U....US1.0...U.
.
Google Inc1%0#..U....Google Internet Authority G20..
140423121609Z.
140722000000Z0f1.0  ..U....US1.0...U...
California1.0...U...
Mountain View1.0...U.
.
Google Inc1.0...U....*.google.com0...."0
.   *...H......
..........0....
..............&gt;..........:...z...S...5...%f............-....*J...i.......c}m......N%...t....G..f.......y.........0x...F.........:......k...k$......!............I...A...........A...G.......q...C...g........r.......b....6.......c...|X.........F...?qs......'.........................mrM.....D....9...
....$...v... .........=.........amAdo..V.....................@.../...   U~....r......... .........g_    ...[y...7=...i... &gt;......b......s...........W......#w..............e..........yI.........{..............0.....0...U.%..0...+.........+.......0.........U..........0.......*.google.com...
*.android.com....*.appengine.google.com....*.cloud.google.com....*.google-analytics.com....*.google.ca....*.google.cl....*.google.co.in....*.google.co.jp....*.google.co.uk....*.google.com.ar....*.google.com.au....*.google.com.br....*.google.com.co....*.google.com.mx....*.google.com.tr....*.google.com.vn....*.google.de....*.google.es....*.google.fr....*.google.hu....*.google.it....*.google.nl....*.google.pl....*.google.pt....*.googleapis.cn....*.googlecommerce.com....*.googlevideo.com...
*.gstatic.com...
*.gvt1.com....*.urchin.com....*.url.google.com....*.youtube-nocookie.com...
*.youtube.com....*.youtubeeducation.com....*.ytimg.com....android.com....g.co....goo.gl....google-analytics.com...
google.com....googlecommerce.com...
urchin.com....youtu.be....youtube.com....youtubeeducation.com0h..+.........0Z0+..+.....0.....http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt0+..+.....0.....http://clients1.google.com/ocsp0...U.........XV.H...%....r..!.......y...'0...U.........00...U.#..0.....J............h...v...b....Z.../0...U. ..0.0..
+.......y...00..U...)0'0%...#...!....http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crl0
.   *...H......
..........A...d...A~A..0...P-JY/........"..M...N.=...H....n%...A......u......2...X......I........F...%....%p..............K...j...A.............g$Y...h....K....E...m......s/......t.....S..SN...Wo.B6.......a......|.............q........?.............y...N....K=....1......|+......3=.....6....j...&amp;...H?.1.....X.H..#V".k.............-.....C.....5S......$.G............eMY(...1+,.e...v"......K...C...}.....V............28K......[......4A.Vr.......C0....?0....'...................K0....0
.   *...H......
....0I1.0   ..U....US1.0...U.
```

I have to compare these segments to find similarities, i.e. to find whether the two programs wrote/read similar content to/from the filesystem. Also, since there are many i/o operations (100s) and many reports (10000s), I should do it pretty quickly. I am working with java.

Any advices?

Comment: How do you define "similar" content?

Comment: That's one of the issues XD

Comment: Compare each character/ set of characters against the entire second document(s) :P

Comment: That would be quite a burden sir XD

Comment: I would extract strings of 3 or more letters, index them for both documents, then compare theae indexes for similarity.

Comment: Well the example had some human readable string because it was extracted from a certificate negotiation, but in general there may be none of such strings.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the Normalized Compression Distance. I don't know yet if this is the best approach for my data anyway...